# simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I am using "**simple_html_dom.php**" to scrap the data from the Wikipedia site. If I run the code in [scraperwiki.com](http://scraperwiki.com) it's throwing an error as **exit status 139**  and if run the same code in my xampp sever, the server is hanging.

1. I have a set of links
2. I'm trying to get **Literacy** value from all the sites
3. If I run the code with one link there is no problem and it's returning the expected result
4. If I try to get data from all the sites in one go I'm facing the above problem

The code is:

```
<?php 
  $test=array
  ( 
   0 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andhra_Pradesh",
   1 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arunachal_Pradesh",
   2 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assam",
   3 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihar",
   4 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chhattisgarh",
   5 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa",

   for($ix=0;$ix<=9;$ix++){

     $content = file_get_html($test[$ix]);
     $tables = $content ->find('#mw-content-text table',0);
     foreach ($tables ->children() as $child1) {
        foreach($child1->find('th a') as $ele){
        if($ele->innertext=="Literacy"){
                foreach($child1->find('td') as $ele1){
                   echo $ele1->innertext;
   }}}  }}
```

Guide me where am wrong. Is there any memory problem??? Is there any xampp configuration???

Comment: Wrap the code bettween the loop in a function. Then run the function inside the loop. It will prevent memory leak.

Comment: try adding `set_time_limit($seconds)` above

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  require 'simple_html_dom.php';
  $test = array( 
   0 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andhra_Pradesh",
   1 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arunachal_Pradesh",
   2 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assam",
   3 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihar",
   4 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chhattisgarh",
   5 => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa");

  for($ix=0;$ix<=count($test);$ix++){
    $content = file_get_html($test[$ix]);
    $tables = $content ->find('#mw-content-text table',0);
    foreach ($tables ->children() as $child1) {
      foreach($child1->find('th a') as $ele){
        if($ele->innertext=="Literacy"){
          foreach($child1->find('td') as $ele1){
            echo $ele1->innertext;
          }
        }
      }
    }   
    $content->clear(); 
  }
?>
```

but these URLs are too much. You may get a fatal error of `max execution time execeeded` or you may get `error 324`.

Comment: have to add the following code at the end of the for loop $content->clear();