# simple html dom and text fields

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
<tr>
    <th nowrap="" align="RIGHT" valign="TOP">Address:</th>
    <td dir="ltr">
       Address: 505 8TH AVENUE, SUITE 603, NEW  YORK, NY, 10018, United States.
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th nowrap="" align="RIGHT" valign="TOP">Date:</th>
    <td dir="ltr">2011</td>
</tr>
```

I have an html source that looks similar to this, I would like to use simple_html_dom (as I am currently using this for the project already) to be able to find the parent text Address and get the child text `Address: 505 8TH AVENUE, SUITE 603, NEW  YORK, NY, 10018, United States`
The problem is there appears to be no unique identifying html elements, how to approach this problem?

Comment: How about using attributes like `id` and `class` ?

Comment: contents of TD that is after TH with innertext of `Address:` ?

Comment: @Waygood how do you do that with simple_html_dom?

Comment: This should point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729152/simple-html-dom-php

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done with simple_html_dom because it lacks sibling selectors. With phpquery you could:

```
$doc->find('th:contains("Address:") + td')->text();
$doc->find('th:contains("Date:") + td')->text();
```

Comment: can you elaborate more: I posted the full source here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430802/simple-html-dom-returning-string-instead-of-array

Comment: I don't understand the explanation you gave, "because it lacks sibling selectors" what are sibling selectors, how are they different and how do you know that simple html dom needs them

Comment: Instead of answering that I'm going to recommend that you do a google search for `css sibling selector` and take the time to familiarize yourself with css in general.