# simple html dom returning string instead of array

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have the following code

```
$html3->find('TR[d=lt]',0);
```

for the following source code

```
<TR>
<TH NOWRAP ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP> Date:</TH>
<TD d="lt">
  2011-05-31 </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH NOWRAP ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>Title:</TH>
<TD d="lt">
  NETWORKS</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH NOWRAP ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>Title:</TH>
<TD d="lt">
 Low NETWORKS</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH NOWRAP ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>Description:</TH>
<TD d="lt">
 CD</TD>
</TR>
```

however the code only returns as an string the DATE instead of the an array of all the vaules,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wow that's pretty sparse on your question code.

However, take a look here:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find

You will find that passing in the int as the second arg tells  the function you are looking for a specific element. Get rid of the second arg and you should get an array of all results back.